# Weblogic Server admin console's 'Monitoring' tab for any server does not respond. Why?

Tags: server, weblogic, monitoring, weblogic12c

All servers started normally and are healthy. All tabs(Configuration, Protocols, Logging, Debug, Control, Deployments, Services, Security, Notes) display respective info and sub-tabs, for all servers, except 'Monitoring'. When 'Monitoring' tab(for all servers) is clicked, the console does not respond. Why? Afterwards, if any other option/link is clicked, the console responds aptly.

**Environment:**

1. WLS 12c - production mode on Windows 10, on my lappy.
2. Cluster on a single machine with 1 Admin server and 3 managed servers, and a node manager.
3. A simple, helloworld, webapp deployed on the cluster which is running fine for all servers.

**Note:**

1. There are no errors in logs.
2. The environment(cluster/admin server/managed servers/node manager) was started and stoped in many combinations, many times, not to solve this problem but as part of practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to run AdminServer (startWebLogic.cmd) as Administrator (windows administrator).

Comment: I'm curious to learn - what made you think about that option?

Comment: What is special/different about 'Monitoring' tab that it requires the server to start with admin privileges?

Comment: WebLogic Server 12c displays patch informations in the monitoring tab. Unfortunatly, to get these informations WebLogic server needs admin rights under Windows. You can also see that the server is very long to start the server tries to get patch information and write them in the log. This issue does not exist under linux.

Comment: you can take thread dumps when it's executing the request when pressing "monitoring", then you can see what it's doing WLS underneath, and it's what @EmmanuelCollin comments.

Comment: I had the same problem. The root privilege has solved the problem for me.